# How can I use lookbehind in a C# Regex in order to skip matches of repeated prefix patterns?

Tags: c#, regex, lookbehind

How can I use lookbehind in a C# Regex in order to skip matches of repeated prefix patterns?

Example - I'm trying to have the expression match all the `b` characters following any number of `a` characters:

```
Regex expression = new Regex("(?<=a).*");

foreach (Match result in expression.Matches("aaabbbb"))
  MessageBox.Show(result.Value);
```

returns `aabbbb`, the lookbehind matching only an `a`. How can I make it so that it would match all the `a`s in the beginning?

I've tried

```
Regex expression = new Regex("(?<=a+).*");
```

and

```
Regex expression = new Regex("(?<=a)+.*");
```

with no results...

What I'm expecting is `bbbb`.

Comment: What's your exptected result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you looking for a repeated capturing group?

```
(.)\1*
```

This will return two matches.

Given:

```
aaabbbb
```

This will result in:

```
aaa
bbbb
```

This:

```
(?<=(.))(?!\1).*
```

Uses the above principal, first checking that the finding the previous character, capturing it into a back reference, and then asserting that that character is not the next character.

That matches:

```
bbbb
```

Comment: I need the lookbehind group to match all the a chars. That is, the actual match is bbbb, as the group of repeated a should be ignored.

Comment: @luvieere:  I have made that change.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out eventually:

```
Regex expression = new Regex("(?<=a+)[^a]+");

foreach (Match result in expression.Matches(@"aaabbbb"))
   MessageBox.Show(result.Value);
```

I must not allow the `a`s to me matched by the non-lookbehind group. This way, the expression will only match those `b` repetitions that follow `a` repetitions.

Matching `aaabbbb` yields `bbbb` and matching `aaabbbbcccbbbbaaaaaabbzzabbb` results in `bbbbcccbbbb`, `bbzz` and `bbb`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the look-behind is skipping the "a" is because it is consuming the first "a" (but no capturing it), then it captures the rest.

Would this pattern work for you instead? New pattern: `\ba+(.+)\b`
It uses a word boundary `\b` to anchor either ends of the word. It matches at least one "a" followed by the rest of the characters till the word boundary ends. The remaining characters are captured in a group so you can reference them easily.

```
string pattern = @"\ba+(.+)\b";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches("aaabbbb", pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Match: " + m.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Group capture: " + m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

**UPDATE:** If you want to skip the first occurrence of *any* duplicated letters, then match the rest of the string, you could do this:

```
string pattern = @"\b(.)(\1)*(?<Content>.+)\b";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches("aaabbbb", pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Match: " + m.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Group capture: " + m.Groups["Content"].Value);
}
```

Comment: Do it without having 'b' or 'a' in your regex.

Comment: @John thanks I was fixated on the letter "a" specifically. My 2nd sample works with any duplicated character and without hardcoding it.

Comment: Alright, +1, I would argue that mine is a little more concise, but it looks like this is easier to read.