# What regex to use in C# to start matching from a word BEHIND (matching backwards...) until a match?

Tags: c#, regex

Let's say a code in HTML:

```
<a href="http://google.com">this is a search engine</a>"
```

How to look for "engine" and match anything until "this" gets reached?

I know I can do: `this.*?engine` - but this is from left to right matching, that is "ahead" matching, here I want to read backwards if this is possible at all?

Comment: Use lookbehind. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839702/how-can-i-use-lookbehind-in-a-c-sharp-regex-in-order-to-skip-matches-of-repeated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reverse all strings and perform normal search:

```
string text = @"<a href=""http://google.com""> this is a search engine </a>";
string engine = "engine";
string strThis = "this";

new string(
  Regex.Match(
    new string(text.Reverse().ToArray()),
    new string(engine.Reverse().ToArray()) + ".+" + new string(strThis.Reverse().ToArray()))
 .Value
 .Reverse()
 .ToArray())
```

Also, to make code clearer, you could define extension method on a `string`, which reverses string and returns `string` instead of `IEnumerable<char>`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string) for reference.

Comment: cool, interesting solution. I usually always use regex (yes slower) but since yours works and i bet it's faster so I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

First, always parse HTML with a dedicated tool, see [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107) for possible options.

Once the HTML is parsed you can get plain text to run your regex against.

You may still use your `this.*?engine` regex *but* enable [`RegexOptions.RightToLeft`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.righttoleft?view=netframework-4.8) option, possibly coupled with `RegexOptions.Singleline` to match really any chars between the two words:

```
var result = Regex.Match(text, @"this.*?engine", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.RightToLeft)?.Value;
```

See the [online regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=this.*%3Fengine&i=blah%20blah%20this%20is%20a%20this%20search%20engine%20blah&o=r&s=43).

As per the documentation, `RegexOptions.RightToLeft`

> Gets a value that indicates whether the regular expression searches from right to left.

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/dOrbWg):

```
var text = "blah blah this is a this search engine blah";
var result = Regex.Match(text, @"this.*?engine", 
        RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.RightToLeft)?.Value;
Console.WriteLine(result); // => this search engine
```